# Is Azure Default AKS load balancer needed when nginx ingress controller is created

Tags: azure-aks

I am confused how Azure provided default Load Balancer works with Ingress controller in the cluster. I can see when a new AKS cluster is created then AKS public LB,Public IP is created along with AKS cluster. However when I create nginx ingress controller it creates new external public IP.I can assign existing Front End Ip address to ingress controller but wondering does AKS load balancer needs to exist along with nginx ingress controller , how it works internally and can I delete default AKS load balancer and only ingress controller of Loadbalancer type is only needed.
The only thing I can imagine is Azure AKS Load balancer manages at network layer so it handles backend VM/VMSS and Nginx ( Ingress Controller ) handles Layer 7 features to handle http request coming after Azure AKS LB delegates the request to it. Kindly explain how is the end to end network flow works.

Comment: Kubernetes talks to the Azure APIs and creates a LB when you request it.

When you create the Nginx Ingress Controller it just connects to that LB.

The short answer is yes, you need the LB as it is also how you set up firewalls, Network Security Groups and so on.

Comment: Ok, so shall I understand this way that when a http request comes to AKS , it first hits Azure LB via Front End IPs and then it delegates to downstream back end IP's ( VMSS, VM's etc.) which further is forwaded to the Ingress Controller ( nginx kind Kubernetus LB type ) before reaching to downstream Kubernetus Services using ingress rules ?

Comment: Yes, but the ingress rules are mapped to the Ingress Controller, so it will be routed from there to the endpoint :)